# I would Insert a text on image button in kottlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, imagebutton

I want to put a text right in the middle of my button, but only with the possible button, but I have an image button

<ImageButton

```
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_width="469dp"
    android:layout_height="171dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView6"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.532"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView6"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView6"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.16"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/bodybalance_desktop_fw20_com_selects_artworking2_960x560" />
```

Comment: Hi, you should edit your question and set first part of your component "<ImageButton" inside code part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `button` on top of the `imagebutton` and set the `backgroundTint` of the `button` to `null` so it becomes transparent and only shows the text on it